# Export group prices - CSV vs. Dataflow

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, csv, importexport, export

We want to be able to export specific product data in MS XML Format using Dataflow.
I realized it does not export group prices, whereas the CSV standard export does this. I couldn't see any option to either

1. get group prices to be part of XML or
2. change standard export to other format than CSV

It doesn't even make sense to have a drop-down to select the format, if only CSV is there.

Does anyone have a solution for this?